# Displaying content of multiple inline divs on bottom

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have two questions:

Q1. I need to display the contents of DIV at the bottom and have tried `vertical-align:bottom;` and `align-items: flex-end;` but none of them works. In the screen shot below, I have shown where I want to display the images. Actually, I am trying to display images near to the horizontal divider. The lower section worked without any effort since it was already appearing on top :)

Q2. My content is vertically grouped in upper and lower sections, such as :

1. **Group1**: 1-Flag-AddIcone
2. **Group2**: 2-Flag-AddIcon
3. **Group3**: 3-Flag-AddIcon
4. **Group4**: 4-AddIcon-Tick
5. **Group5**: 5-AddIcon-Tick
6. **Group6**: 6-AddIcon-Tick

I want to create a hover effect using CSS so that when the mouse goes over any section of the group, the whole group is highlighted. The problem is, Numbers are not in the same div. I could've put them in the same div but I am asking for this problem because creating hover effect on other DIVs is also required in other sections of my application.

[image]

Following is my code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    #line01Div{
        height:20px;
    }
    #line02Div{
        height:90px;
    }
    #line03Div{
        border-top:3px solid #878C87;
    }
    #line04Div{
        display:inline-block;
        height:60px;
    }
    #line05Div{
        height:30px;
    }
    .rnDiv{
        display:inline-block;
        text-align:center;
        width:40px;
        height:20px;
    }
    .ImageDiv1{
        border:1px solid;
        height:87px;
        width:40px;
        display:inline-block;
        #vertical-align:bottom;
        align-items: flex-end;
    }
    .ImageDiv1:hover{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .ImageDiv2{
        height:149px;
        width:40px;
        text-align:center;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    .imgSize{
        max-width:85%;
        max-height:85%;
    }
</style>
<div id="line01Div">
      <div class="rnDiv">1</div><!--
    --><div class="rnDiv">2</div><!--
    --><div class="rnDiv">3</div>
</div>  
<div id="line02Div">
    <div class="ImageDiv1"><img class="imgSize" src="Flagredicon.png" alt="" /><img class="imgSize" src="save_data.png" alt="" /></div><!--
    --><div class="ImageDiv1"><img class="imgSize" src="Flagredicon.png" alt="" /><img class="imgSize" src="save_data.png" alt="" /></div><!--
    --><div class="ImageDiv1"><img class="imgSize" src="Flagredicon.png" alt="" /><img class="imgSize" src="save_data.png" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<div id="line03Div">        
</div>
<div id="line04Div">
    <div class="ImageDiv2"><img class="imgSize" src="save_data.png" alt="" /><img class="imgSize" src="tick.png" alt="" /></div><!--
    --><div class="ImageDiv2"><img class="imgSize" src="save_data.png" alt="" /><img class="imgSize" src="tick.png" alt="" /></div><!--
    --><div class="ImageDiv2"><img class="imgSize" src="save_data.png" alt="" /><img class="imgSize" src="tick.png" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<div id="line05Div">
      <div class="rnDiv ">4</div><!--
    --><div class="rnDiv ">5</div><!--
    --><div class="rnDiv ">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a `span` tag to group your `img` pairs and then `absolute` `position` the span to the `bottom`.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/05yd0mjf/

CSS

```
.ImageDiv1 span{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="ImageDiv1">
    <span>
    <img class="imgSize" src="Flagredicon.png" alt="" />
    <img class="imgSize" src="save_data.png" alt="" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say you want to highlight an entire group, what constitutes a group? Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/05yd0mjf/1/

Comment: No, The numeric and the two images form one group. like this http://jsfiddle.net/05yd0mjf/4/. Just to explain, I have displayed the numeric within the images Div but my requirement is to keep the numerics in separate div but create a hover effect from other div.

Comment: That would not be possible in CSS only. It would be very easy to do in jQuery though.